# SignalR with pool of background tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, signalr

I have an asp.net application I am building that allows a user to select a game server, and then view the game session information in real-time. I want to use SignalR to get real-time updates on the client side regarding the state of the game.

To do this I want to create a background thread that is unique to each server. If a user has clicked to view server 1, and there are no active connections in signalr to that server, some process should push a background thread that polls the database every few seconds for data on that game, and push that data out to clients in signalR. If all signalr clients disconnect from that server, the thread should stop polling the database and terminate gracefully.

If a user has clicked to view a server, and there are clients already connected to that hub, then the client should just register and handle the callbacks that are already being managed in the signalR hub.

The problem I am having trouble figuring out is how to:

1. Differentiate between different signalR callbacks 
   (ie. Ensure client A is receiving data for server A, and not server B). Unique server data is obtained via serverID, so the method signature in the hub is the same across all clients and sessions. (ie. GameHub.UpdateGame(GameModel model) should return the appropriate GameModel for that particular serverID for those clients viewing that server).
2. Manage the background thread pool - how can I manage when to add new threads for new serverID sessions, and remove threads that have no client connections listening?

Comment: Honestly this doesn't seem like a situation where push instead of polling is worth the complexities. It's more fun admittedly. You'll simply need a method that registers and unregisters clients for specific groups. When the first client registers for a group start your timer which gets the data and sends it to the group. If at callback time no valid clients are in the group anymore stop the timer.

Comment: The only real complexity is dealing with the case where the last user of a group intermittently disconnects and automatically reconnects - you'll have to write a pipeline module that restarts the timer in that case. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#verifying-group-membership-when-reconnecting for an example of such a class.

Comment: @Voo would the pipeline module only apply if I am tracking subscription in the onConnect, onDisconnect handlers? I currently am thinking using subscribe() and unsubscribe() on page load and before page unload. If signalr experiences temporary disruption,i dont think it would be an issue unless the page was to be unloaded (user navigates away for example).